# UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to take input and convert that to a .csv file then create a directory for the folder and save that file within the directory. Once I run my code, I'm able to create the directory and file. However, this is supposed to happen after I click the button and does so before. The exception is thrown right after I click the button. I'm using WPF and coding in C#. What would cause this exception?

Here is a snippet

```
private void updateBANKEevent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        //Convert input to CSV format
        string userInput = tellerID.Text + "," + vaultSerial.Text + "," + QR.Text;
        var bnkDir = @"C:\Program Files\Bank_Data";


        //generate headers for CSV file
        if (!Directory.Exists(bnkDir))
        {
            string bnkHeader = "tellerID" + "," + "Vault Serial Number" + "," + "QR Code" + Environment.NewLine;
            Directory.CreateDirectory(bnkDir); <--Exception is thrown here
            File.WriteAllText(System.IO.Path.Combine(bnkDir,"Bank_Data.csv"), bnkHeader + userInput);

        }

        // Append new input to existing file
        File.AppendAllText(System.IO.Path.Combine(bnkDir),userInput + Environment.NewLine);
        }
```

Comment: you can't create a folder in program files if your app isn't elevated. Create the folder in a userfolder instead

Comment: Since Windows Vista, apps are - by default - not given write access to `C:\Program Files` and `C:\Program Files (x86)`. The correct place to write your files to is `%APPDATA%\<your app>`

Comment: The user is not authorized for the C:\Program Files folder. Try writing to some other authorized folder, or you would need to run as a user authorized to access C:\Program Files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is quite clear. The user is not authorised to create the specified directory.

Given that the folder is "C:\Program Files\Bank_Data" it will be the case that a regular user won't have the rights to create files or directories whereas an admin user (which you probably are) will.

You need to choose a folder that *all* users have rights to to store your data, which by default will be `%APPDATA%\<your app>`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! 

It is creating the folder and file, but still throwing the exception when I click on the update button.

Comment: @fuser If it's the same exception then the user won't have the necessary rights to perform the operation.

Comment: It seems to be on the AppendAllText function line. I'm passing it the name of the directory, and yes it is the same exception again.

Comment: @fuser Yes. The user won't have rights to the file (I know that sounds odd, but you can have rights to create something but then not amend it).

Comment: Hmm, how would you suggest to correct that then? I'm a bit new in dealing with file permissions.

Comment: @fuser Have you changed the directory you're writing to to one where the user will have all necessary permissions? Beyond that it's just a matter of debugging. Trap the exception and see if you can see exactly why it's failing from the information returned in the exception.

Comment: Yes, I changed it to %APPDATA%\  . It now creates that folder on my desktop and the secondary folder with the file in it.